# Why is my class accessing another class that was not imported?

Tags: python, class, import, module

I have multiple classes stored in a module called car.py. One class uses another. Here is the code.

```
from car import ElectricCar
my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
```

The ElectricCar class uses the Battery class stored in the same module, yet Battery is not imported.

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
"""Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """
        Initialize attributes of the parent class.
        Then initialize attributes specific to an electric car.
        """
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()
```

Here is the parent class Car from the same module car.py.

```
class Car():
"""A simple attempt to represent a car."""

def __init__(self, make, model, year):
    """Initialize attributes to describe the car."""
    self.make = make
    self.model = model
    self.year = year
    self.odometer_reading = 0
```

Here is the Battery class from the same module car.py.

```
class Battery():
"""A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""

    def __init__(self, battery_size=70):
        """Initialize the battery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = battery_size

    def describe_battery(self):
         """Print a statement describing the battery size."""
         print(f"This car has a {self.battery_size}-kwh battery!")

    def get_range(self):
    """Print a statement about the range this battery provides."""
        if self.battery_size == 70:
            range = 240
        elif self.battery_size == 85:
            range = 270

        message = f"This car can go approximately {range}"
        message += " mile on a full charge."
        print(message)

    def upgrade_battery(self):
        if self.battery_size == 70:
            self.battery_size = 85
```

And finally the code I use to create and use the object.

```
my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
my_tesla.battery.describe_battery()
my_tesla.battery.get_range()
my_tesla.battery.upgrade_battery()
my_tesla.battery.get_range()
```

The code works just fine. My question is how, when I import ElectricCar, is it able to access the Battery class when I did not import Battery specifically. As a follow up question, which is similar, how is it that the super() method is able to access the parent class when the parent class was not imported either? Is this how python naturally operates?

Comment: I think the instant you try to instantiate the object you'll get an error.

Comment: As I mentioned before, the code works fine. I was expecting an error but never received one. That's why I'm confused

Comment: Do `my_car = ElectricCar()`. Defining the class works fine but it should break once you use it (once you instantiate the object)
.

Comment: After instantiation I run, my_tesla.battery.describe_battery() which accesses a method defined in the Battery class. That also works fine

Comment: In that case you must provide a minimal, verifiable, and complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. All I can see in your question is the class definition, not what you do after you create any objects. For me to help I must be able to reproduce your results.

Comment: The edit I just made should be enough to give you the whole scope now. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hold up, you state that all these classes are from `car.py`. If all of them are from the same file you don't need to import anything. You only need to import things in other files. By default anything in file `X.py` can access everything else in `X.py` since they are defined in the same namespace.

Comment: Forgive me, all of the classes are in car.py. I am in another py file importing strictly only the ElectricCar class. 'from car import ElectricCar'
'my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)' are in electric_car.py along with the code at the bottom of my post

Comment: Yes. No imports are necessary since they're from the same file. By default everything in a file can access every other thing in that file. Only if you move `Battery` for example to `Battery.py` would you have to import it.

Comment: But `ElectricCar` is defined in `car.py` no? When you import `ElectricCar` python brings that name from the other file into your file. The other classes are still defined just not present in your namespace.

Comment: You don't have to import every single dependency to use something defined elsewhere - you just have to import that singular thing. Python handles the rest in the background. The definition for `Battery` is still located in `car.py` so it's able to access the things in `car.py`. On the other hand if you redefined `Battery` in the current file it would throw an error since the things it references isn't in the file that it's defined in.

Comment: Ah I see. So since the ElectricCar class uses the Battery class, and me only importing ElectricCar, python understands that Battery is used by ElectricCar and does the rest of the work for me?

Comment: Yep that's a way to think about it. Regardless, to use something defined in another file you don't have to import all of the dependencies, just that one thing.

Comment: My goodness. Thank you so much, you've been a great help. Have a fantastic day!

Comment: Happy to help :)